# commenting asynchronously -- on php using ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I've included the code that I'm working with. I'm trying to make comments appear asynchronously on my website that runs on php with ajax. Currently, I have a database that takes in the user input (which is what insert.php handles). I'm able to input the user input into my database and also print it out, however it does not print out the comment on the index.php site without reloading. The goal is to have it print out the user input automatically, without reloading the site. Right now what happens is, once I press the submit button, it takes me to a white page and once I open up the index.php page again, the comment shows up. Something is going wrong or not linking properly, not entirely sure what.

index.php

```
<html>
<head>

    <link href="csair.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />
    <script   src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        $(function() {
            $('#submitButton').click(function() {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: "insert.php",
                    data: {name: $('#userInput').val()},
                    , beforeSend: function(){
                }
                , complete: function(){
                }
                , success: function(html){
                    $("comment_part").html(html);
                }
            });
          });
       });
    </script>

</head>
<body>

<HR SIZE="6">

<form id="comment_form" action="insert.php" method="GET">
    Comments:
    <input type="text" class="text_cmt" name="field1_name" id="userInput"/>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" id = "submitButton"/>
    <input type='hidden' name='parent_id' id='parent_id' value='0'/>
</form>

<!--connects to database and queries to print out on site-->
<div id='comment_part'>
<?php
    $link = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'x', '', 'comment_schema');
    $query="SELECT COMMENTS FROM csAirComment";
    $results = mysqli_query($link,$query);

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results)) {
        echo '<div class="comment" >';
        $output= $row["COMMENTS"];
        //protects against cross site scripting
        echo htmlspecialchars($output ,ENT_QUOTES,'UTF-8');
        echo '</div>';
    }
?>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

insert.php

```
$userInput= $_GET["field1_name"];
if(!empty($userInput)) {
    $field1_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $userInput);
    $field1_name_array = explode(" ",$field1_name);

    foreach($field1_name_array as $element){
        $query = "SELECT replaceWord FROM changeWord WHERE badWord = '" . $element . "' ";
        $query_link = mysqli_query($link,$query);
        if(mysqli_num_rows($query_link)>0){
            $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query_link);
            $goodWord = $row['replaceWord'];
            $element= $goodWord;
        }
        $newComment = $newComment." ".$element;
    }

    //Escape user inputs for security
    $sql = "INSERT INTO csAirComment (COMMENTS) VALUES ('$newComment')";
    $result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);
    //attempt insert query execution

    //header("Location:index.php");
    die();

    mysqli_close($link);
}
else{
    die('comment is not set or not containing valid value');
}


$link = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'x', '', 'comment_schema');
$query="SELECT COMMENTS FROM csAirComment";
$results = mysqli_query($link,$query);

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results)) {
    echo '<div class="comment" >';
    $output= $row["COMMENTS"];
    //protects against cross site scripting
    echo htmlspecialchars($output ,ENT_QUOTES,'UTF-8');
    echo '</div>';
}
```

Comment: (1) You are not preventing the default action of a form, which is to go to `insert.php`. You need a `event.PreventDefault()` in your `$('#submitButton').click(function(event){...}`. (2) After fixing #1, you will have an issue with your `$.ajax()` as your `insert.php` has `$userInput= $_GET["field1_name"];`, but your `$.ajax()` is sending `name` -> `data: {name: $('#userInput').val()}`.

Comment: so for my second error, should it be, name: $('#field1_name').val() instead?

Comment: also, for the event.PreventDefault(), does that need to do something or can I just call it?

Comment: for the 2nd error it should be `data : { field1_name : $('#userInput').val() },` (or `data : { field1_name : $('input[name="field1_name"]').val() },`). The issue was `name`!=`field1_name`, or specifically `$_GET["name"]`!=`$_GET["field1_name"]`.

Comment: [`event.preventDefault()`](https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/) is a jquery method that prevent default event from triggering, ie. prevents the form from going to `insert.php`. You just need to call it inside your `$('#submitButton').click(function(event){...}`, but notice that you need to add the `event` inside the `function(event)`. (you could also simplify it to `e`, ie `$('#submitButton').click(function(e){ e.preventDefault(); $.ajax({ ... }); }`

Comment: thank you, but I'm still having the same error. It's just taking me to a blank white page and when I open up the index.php file again, it shows me the input.

Comment: My guess is because you have a syntax error in your javascript, most likely the extra comma in `data: {name: $('#userInput').val()}, , beforeSend: function(){` (notice the comma after `data`, and then another just before `beforeSend`. If you looked at your browser console, it would probably tell you that your have a javascript error/issue.

Comment: sorry, i'm completely new to this. I tried the browser console and it doesn't show that I have any javascript error, but right now what happens is that the page doesn't reload, but I have to manually reload in order to see what the user inputs. It doesn't take me to a white page so I guess the bug is gone, but it isn't adding to my page on it's own. I need to reload myself to see what has been added

Comment: Do you mean you, as the user, what you posted or someone else, as the user on another browser/page what they posted?

Comment: well, when I run it on a browser. I input something pretending to be the user.

Comment: You are missing the `#` (id selector) in `$("comment_part").html(html);`. It should be `$("#comment_part").html(html);`. Right now it doesn't know where to place the `.html(html)`

Comment: is window.location.reload() not needed to reload the page?